# How to validate an object against a group of constraints

Tags: javascript

I've recently came upon a challenge that required me to validate if the passed object into the function is for one: an object; for two: is not an empty object. other than that, I would have to check against the keys and values of said object and validate whether they're in the required range, is not NaN, not undefined, not null...etc. I would ofcourse have to throw an error in case any of the above constraints were to be seen/met in the object. now the way I dealt with it was something like this:

```
function validateEntries(key, value) { 
    if(typeof key !== 'number' || key == undefined || key == null || key == '') {
        throw new Error('Key is not a number');
    } else if (typeof value == 'number' || value == undefined || value == null || key == '') {
        throw new Error('Value is not a number'); 
    } else {
    return true; 
}

function validateObject(object) {
    if(typeof object !== 'object' || Object.entries(object).length === 0) {
        throw new Error('Object is not an object, is empty'); 
}

function result(object) {


validateObject(object); 
for([key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {

try {
    validateEntries(key, value); 
} catch(e) {
    console.error(e); 
}
   
}
```

as I was writing this, I kept thinking there must be a better way to check/validate an object's keys and values against a group of constraints/conditions and throw errors accordingly. something similar to how the library `joi` would do it but I wonder if there's a pattern of some sort to do it without any libraries using vanilla javascript.

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the right code? `for ([key, value] of object)` is not a valid loop for an object afaik and I don't think you want to throw `Value is not a number` when `typeof value == 'number'`

Comment: And what about writing the constraints in a list and then iterating over it? e.g. `const valueConstraints = [isNumber, notNan, ...]`  (potentially also as inline arrow functions if you want)

Comment: @A_A my bad, I meant `Object.entries(object)`